# CMOS Source Follower Pole Location

Tags: frequency, cmos

[image]

I have tried computing the location of the poles in a source-follower CMOS circuit.

I am assuming that the gain is close to 1 of the source-follower buffer. By using the miller approximation, it seems to suggest that there is no effect of Cgs and there is only a single pole at the output due to the load capacitance.

Am I doing something wrong?
I have a feeling I can't assume the gain is 1. I need to account for the Cl in my gain. Is that the issue?

And yes, I am ignoring CGD

Comment: You are right if the gain of a follower was exactly equal to 1. But the problem is that the voltage of a source follower will be lower than one.

Comment: Just for completeness, I take it we don't need to worry about Vg, Vs or Id, simply that it is biased, and thus gives some gm? What is r_o?

Answer (score 0):

> *Am I doing something wrong? I have a feeling I can't assume the gain
> is 1*

I always assume that a source follower has a gain of about 0.5 but, you can verify this with a simulator or work through the data sheet. This them means that C<sub>GS</sub> "projects" about 50% of its data sheet value to the gate with respect to ground.

Comment: 50% indicates RL = 1/gm. The question shows a CCS load and no load resistance however, so gain will be 1, or only very slightly less. Well, there is an r_o given but not drawn anywhere, I don't get that.